# populating more type of similar objects in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a `canvas`,I am using it to draw balls.However I want to populate balls from 1 to say 10 balls at random space within the canvas.Should i use 10 seperate functions(`drawBall1()`,`drawBall2`,....,`drawBall10`)?

**OR**

Are there any other methods?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ballRadius = 10;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function draw() {
  drawBall();
}
function drawBall() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
}
draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create object that describe the ball and has functions that can draw or other behaviours

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function createBall(x,y,radius,color){
    return {               // return a new ball
        x,y,radius,color,  // set the balls properties
        draw(ctx){         // add a draw function
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.fill();
            return this; // to allow chaining
        },
    }
}
const colors = "#C30A4C,#CCAB7C,#CC984B,#DE880C,#546D84,#7F858A,#697785,#375E85,#125290,#94B870";
const ballRadius = 20;
const rand = (size)=>{return Math.floor(Math.random() * size)}; // rand util
const balls = []; // an array to hold the balls
balls.push(       // add some balls to the ball array
    ...colors
    .split(",")
    .map(color=>createBall(
         rand(ctx.canvas.width),
         rand(ctx.canvas.height),
         ballRadius,
         color
     ))
)
balls.forEach(ball=>ball.draw(ctx)); // draw them.
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=200></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just call that one function ten times instead of creating ten functions which do the same thing or you could introduce a loop inside which loops 10 times for you, depedning on what suits you better.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

```js
function drawBall(x, y, radius, color, ctx)
{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var x, y, color,
    colors = ['#ffc0cb', '#008080', '#b0e0e6', '#003366', '#666666', '#faebd7'],
    radius = 10,
    ballCount = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < ballCount; i++)
{
    x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width + 1));
    y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.height + 1));
    color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

    drawBall(x, y, radius, color, ctx);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="200px" height="200px" id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps, I just got your question wrong. What do you mean by a workaround? If you want to repeat one action N-times then loops are meant for it.
It's either some kind of loop or typing ten times the same code.

Comment: yea you are right your way but that thing I know already but thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you more. I really don't understand what the problem is. :(

Comment: no problem  you helped many others who will see this solution